# Does Operation Timed out exception in httpWebRequest.GetResponse() method close the connection

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, system.net

My question might be silly, but need an answer.  As far as I know whenever "**The Operation has timed out**" exception occurs in `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` method than connection is closed and released.  If it is not true than how does it work?  I tried to google this but couldn't get the answer.

**EDIT:** In this case it was a post request, connection was established and the URL which called was processing the request at server end, but HttpWebRequest Object was waiting on response and after sometime exception occurred.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you must call the Close method to close the stream and release the connection. Failure to do so may cause your application to run out of connections. If you are uncertain, you can always put a try/catch block around the `Close` method or the `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()`.

Comment: Which Close method we are talking here?  HttpWebRequest doesn't have Close method and HttpWebResponse not yet initialized here.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not entirely sure but it looks like that the `Operation TimedOut` exception probably faults the underlying connection channel; cause all the request after that ends up with same exception.

Per [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You must call the Close method to close the stream and release the
>   connection. Failure to do so may cause your application to run out of
>   connections.

I did a small trial to see

```
    private static void MakeRequest()
    {
        WebRequest req = null;
        try
        {
            req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.wg.net.pl");
            req.Timeout = 10;                
            req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            req.Timeout = 10000;
            req.GetResponse(); // This as well results in TimeOut exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which Close method we are talking here?  HttpWebRequest doesn't have Close method and HttpWebResponse not yet initialized here.

Comment: @Nps, check the documentation I have linked along with answer. Particularly you should call `Stream.Close()` or `HttpWebResponse.Close()`. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: But exception occurs in `GetResponse()` method which returns HttpWebResponse object which is not return due to exception.  I can't call the Close method on null object.

Comment: @Nps, that's correct and calling close() is more of best practice. In this particular case, I don't see why even calling close() since it's likely be already closed.

Comment: that was my question was, so the exception will automatically close the connection.  We don't need to handle in this particular situation.

Comment: Yes, at least to me it looks like since there is no connection being established in reality.

Comment: Sry I will have to go off now and I won't be able to help any further than what I have already.

Comment: Added more detail in question